# ClassNotFound Exception in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-manifest, stack-trace

While doing the webpage loader using shouldOverrideUrlLoading method finally I am getting the `ClassNotFound Exception`.

**StackTrace:**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311): Process: com.webpageloader, PID: 1311
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.webpageloader/com.webpageloader.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.webpageloader.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.webpageloader-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.webpageloader-1, /system/lib]]
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.webpageloader.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.webpageloader-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.webpageloader-1, /system/lib]]
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1311):    ... 11 more
```

**WebPageLoader.java:**

```
package com.webpageloader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
{
    final Activity activity = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com");
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webpageloader"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.webpageloader.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I doesn't know how to solve these.Anybody can help me with these.Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<activity
            android:name="com.webpageloader.MainActivity">
```

to

```
<activity
            android:name="com.webpageloader.WebPageLoader">
```

The error says `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.webpageloader.MainActivity"`. (JVM) tries to load a particular class and the specified class cannot be found in the classpath. It means there's no class with the name `MainActivity`.

In `AndroidManifest.xml` he has defined  `<activity android:name="com.webpageloader.MainActivity">`, so it is trying to find the class `MainActivity`, but he had renamed that class to `WebPageLoader` and forgot to change in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Just think and solved these `ClassNotFoundException` by changing the `Activity name` in Manifest:

change these

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.webpageloader.MainActivity" >
```

into

```
<activity
            android:name="com.webpageloader.WebPageLoader" >
```

ClassNotFound Exception would be occurred because if we forget to define the Exact Class Name at Manifest.The Exception we seen at the runtime.